# How to update a value in database after n seconds of query made? Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, sqlite, django-models

I have a model in which I created a field "bargain price " as shown in Models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    bargainprice = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

somewhere in my template I take input from user and update the bargain price using ajax as shown below:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "/bargain/" + id + "/",
        data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.CSRF_TOKEN, 'input': parseFloat(input) },
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });
```

and I successfully update the price by the view:

```
def Bargain(request, uid):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      item = Item.objects.get(id=uid)
      item.bargainprice = request.POST['input']
      item.save()
      message = 'update successful'
      return HttpResponse(message)
  else:
      return HttpResponse("this is not working..")
```

**Now what I want. I want to reset this Bargain_price updated value to default after n seconds  **

Can anyone suggest to me the method to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use Celery

Comment: Do you want to do this even if the user is no longer interacting with the webpage? If so, then you'll need something that can carry out tasks periodically in the background like Celery. If you want to reset the price when a user sends another POST request after some time, you can add a `created` timestamp to your `Item` model, compute how long it's been, and write the default instead if it's been too long.